# Android-Aligning a element + margin with relative to parent element

Tags: android-layout

To align a element with respect to an other element using their I can use.

`android:layout_alignLeft` etc..

But how to add a margin or a padding:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/students"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/student" />    

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/student"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/stud_describe"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Padding top in the second `TextView` is not having any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting padding and margin mixed up. Change the second `TextView` to:

```
layout_marginTop="30dp"
```

instead of

```
paddingTop="30dp".
```

Padding pads the `View` itself, making it bigger. Margin changes the position of the `TextView` within its container (`RelativeLayout`) and doesn't alter its size.

Comment: Yes, adding padding will give b=padding between the top of the textview and the inner section of the text.  Whereas, margin will give space between the top of the textview, and the bottom of the item above it.  An easy way to see what you are doing when laying these out is to give your textview a background color.